# 'View in browser' link in Mosiaco template does not work when used with CiviRules or scheduled reminders

Tags: mosaico

I'm finding that whereas the ‘View in browser’ link in a Mosaico template will work when the template is applied to a mailing created via Mailings->New mailing, it will *not* work when the template is applied to a mailing triggered by CiviRules, or a when used by a scheduled reminder.

So:

1. I create a Mosaico template with a 'preheader block' containing a 'View in your browser' link - this link is pre-defined in the preheader and I don't change it in any way
2. I create a new mailing with Mailings->New mailing, specify this template, then click on ‘send test' under ‘Send test email to:’ in first screen ‘Define Mailing’ of New Mailing dialogue. When the email is received, the 'View in your browser' link works as expected
3. I create a CiviRule, with Action 'Send Email', using this template. When the email is received, the 'View in your browser' link does not work - on inspection, the <a> tag has no href attribute
4. I create a scheduled reminder using this template and again when the email is received the link does not work, in the same way

Anyone know what the problem is here?

Answer (score 4):

It seems from your post that you might be using the extension that transfers Mosaico templates for use in non-bulk mail scenarios, is this correct? In any case, the way that Civi stores bulk emails versus regular emails, and the way access is permissioned for each (viewing bulk emails versus viewing activities), suggests to me that the view in browser option only works for bulk emails.  If you're able to remove it from your template for regular email and reminder usage, that might be best.

Comment: We are using Mosaico Message Template Synchronization, which 'enables you to use CiviCRM Mosaico templates with scheduled reminders, personal messages, etc.' so I guess that's the extension you mean. There's a reason I wanted to keep the View in Browser link, but it sounds like I might be attempting the impossible...